# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception for some input values

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

The following is a part of my code. 
For some values of bands and bandRows the code seems to run perfectly alright. But for some it gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.
Any ideas where I might have gone wrong? I cannot find any mistake in the code.
Thanks in advance

```
for(int i=0; i<bands; i++)
        {
            int a=0;
            while(a<bucketSize) 
            { 
                bandBuckets[i][a] = new ArrayList();
                a++;
            }
        }  

    for (int i = 0; i < bands; i++) 
            {          
                for (int j = 0; j < preprocessedList.size(); j++) 
                {
                    int[][] forBuckets = new int[bands][bandRows];

                    for (int k = 0; k < bandRows; k++) 
                    {
                        Arrays.fill(forBuckets[i], Bands[i][k][j]);

                    }

                    bandBuckets[i][h.hashBands(forBuckets[i], bucketSize)].add(j);

                }
            }
```

Here's the h.hashBands() function which is in another class

```
 public int hashBands(int[] in, int bucketSize) 
        {

            int hashVal = 0;
            int k = in.length;
            int base = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
               // for (int j = 0; i < in[i].length; i++) 
                    hashVal += in[i] * Math.pow(base, k - i - 1);
            }
            return hashVal % bucketSize;

        }
```

Comment: Too many arrays, too many dimensions... What is Bands[i][k][j] .... are those dimensions right ....

Comment: yeah they are right. It works perfectly well for some inputs. Only for some, it gives the error

Comment: IMO, this should be in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ChthonicProject - CR is for working code only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is an overflow in your hashBands() function.

The max value for an int is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1. hashVal will overflow when k - i - 1 is greater than 19. In Java, exceptions aren't thrown for overflows and underflows. Consider using a BigInteger and its modPow() function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell where exactly you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.
Seeing your code it seems that there might be some problem while returning from hashBands() function. It might be returning something greater than expected.

```
bandBuckets[i][h.hashBands(forBuckets[i], bucketSize)]
```

For the 2nd dimension of this array h.hashBands(forBuckets[i], bucketSize) --> this value might be greater than the expected value for that part.....

Comment: Yes it's that line                                            bandBuckets[i][h.hashBands(forBuckets[i], bucketSize)].add(j);   But that value should be less than bucketSize. The function hashBands() return the mod of hash value by bucketSize (hashVal % bucketSize). So obviously it is less than the bucketSize..